# Can a database table not have a primary key?

Tags: primary-key, sqlite

Can a database table not have a primary key?  SQLite lets you define a table with no primary key therefore there can be no insertion anomaly.

Comment: Actually, SQLite silently creates a primary key column for your called `rowid`.  If you [expicitly disable `rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) _and_ don't specify a `PRIMARY KEY` column, `CREATE TABLE t1(name TEXT) WITHOUT ROWID;`, it errors out: `Parse error: PRIMARY KEY missing on table t1`. SQLite version 3.39.2 2022-07-21 15:24:47.

Comment: Furthermore, if you skip `WITHOUT ROWID`, though you might specify `PRIMARY KEY` on a column, it's really just a `UNIQUE` column constraint and the true primary key is still `rowid`.  Since `PRIMARY KEY` columns are just unique, and not really primary key, they can also be null. Hence it's [preferred to specify `NOT NULL` the constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#the_primary_key).

Answer (score 19):

*Can* you create a database table without a primary key? Well, you just said you can in SQLite. And, I believe that holds true for almost every (if not every) major DBMS platform.

*Should* you create a database table without a primary key? No.

Every table should have some column (or set of columns) that uniquely identifies one and only one row. It makes it much easier to maintain the data.

It's true, without a primary key (or *some* unique key), you don't have an insertion anomaly if you go to insert the same data multiple times.

What you *do* have is a `user` table with 300 separate entries for a user named "bob", many of which have different values in the other columns. And, if you've tried to connect rows in some other table to `user` without a primary key/foreign key relationship - every row in `message` marked as `sent_by` "bob" ties back to every one of those 300 `user` entries. Oh, and there're 39 unique passwords for "bob" (157 of the rows all show the password "password", of course).

Without primary keys, things can get really messy, really fast.

Comment: I like to say that without a primary key you don't have data, you have junk.

Comment: In MySQL, if you don't create one, a "hidden" one is created for you!

Comment: [SQLite always creates a hidden primary key `rowid`, unless explicitly disabled](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible that a table doesn't have primary key in SQLite as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  name TEXT
);
```